# Removing JavaScript array item without built in functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove an item from a JavaScript array **without** using built in functions like pop() and splice()?

Comment: If it's from the end of the array: `arr.length--;`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you need this?

Comment: Not that I would recommend it (just use the built in functions instead) but you could do a for loop and reconstruct a new array, containing all items except the one you want to get rid of.

Comment: I'm just challenging myself to write a sorting algorithm without using any built in functions. I haven't tried any methods yet because I'm fairly new to programming, and didn't find anything when googling the issue.

Comment: It's unusual for a sorting algorithm to change the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for that

if you want to delete something from beginning

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let [c, d, ...newarr] = arr;
console.log(newarr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the array being reindexed, you can use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), but it will leave an `undefined` entry where the deleted value was, and the `.length` of the array will still be the same as before:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.length, `[${ arr.join(', ') }]`);

delete arr[2];

console.log(arr.length, `[${ arr.join(', ') }]`);
```

If you want to delete elements from the end, you can manually update the `.length` property of the array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.length, `[${ arr.join(', ') }]`);

arr.length = 3;;

console.log(arr.length, `[${ arr.join(', ') }]`);
```

Otherwise, you can use a loop to go through the original elements and push the ones you want to keep to a separate array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(arr.length, `[${ arr.join(', ') }]`);

const even = [];

for (let n of arr) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) even.push(n);
}

console.log(even.length, `[${ even.join(', ') }]`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.slice(0,4));  // [1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.slice(1,5));  // [2,3,4,5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul in the comment section for suggesting `arr.length--;`. Since I was using pop() previously the item I wanted to remove was already at the end so it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own method like below:

```
Array.prototype.removeItem = function(item) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === item) {
            for (var j = i; j < this.length - 1; j++) {
                this[j] = this[j + 1];
            }
            this.length = this.length - 1
            return;
        }
    }
}

var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
items.removeItem('c');
```